# incorrect and indelible Bookmark/Favorite icons in iOS 15 Safari

Tags: macos, ios, safari, bookmarks

I can't correct a website Bookmark/Favorite icon on iOS. (It seems like there are stale cache files of some sort on the iPhone that just refuse to be removed. Looking at `Safari` in Storage Management there continues to be 3.3MB of data after all of my attempts to clean up. Possible that it could just be the database structure that take up that space.)

[image]

I turned off iCloud for Safari on my devices.
I deleted all bookmarks and reset Safari on my mac.
Removed Favicon Cache and Touch Icons Cache on mac.
Cleared Cache and history on my iPhone twice.
Removed all bookmarks and favorites from my iPhone.
Reinstalled BigSur over my BigSur installation.

The website in question is `https://www.teamunify.com` which hosts managed websites using the same base URL:

```
https://www.teamunify.com/team/ilpac/page/home
https://www.teamunify.com/team/iscats/page/home
https://www.teamunify.com/Home.jsp?_tabid_=0&team=ilslsc
https://www.teamunify.com/team/isnasa/page/home
https://www.teamunify.com/team/ilhpac/page/home
```

Whenever I save any of these sites as bookmarks on iOS they all use the Bookmark/Favorite icon of one site only: `https://www.teamunify.com/team/ilhpac/page/home`

Screenshot of Start Page on Safari macOS BigSur
[image]

Screenshot of Start Page on Safari iOS 15.01
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way (possibly the only way) to remove/clear those cached "Favorites" favicons/touch images was simply to toggle the "Favorites" feature off and on. In my case the Favorites feature will only keep one favicon for all three websites because they all use the same domain. So I first visited the page whose favicon I wanted to use for all three of the bookmarks and now they all use that favicon.

You can find the toggle in the "Customize Start Page on iOS" by scrolling to the very bottom and tapping on "Edit". It seems that a domain's favicon/touch icon are indeed indelible after they have been added to Favorites the first time. Meaning the same favicon will be used for subsequent bookmarks that contain the same domain.

The other option is to not add bookmarks into Safari's "Favorites" folder, and use another bookmark folder instead as a "Favorites" folder.

[image: iOS Safari Customize Start Page Screenshot]